# What are the names of the various traditional Spanish dances?

Tags: dance

I have been told that the Spanish named their dances after the regions that they were from.

If the dance came from Granada then they called it a Granadino and if it came from a sleepy fishing village called Malaga then they called it a Malaguena.

What the name of the regional dances of Seville or Madrid are I wonder?

Comment: No clue how long the list gets, but I've read the Seville dances are called [Sevillanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sevillanas).

Comment: The title seems to ask for a list, which is vigorously opposed here. Perhaps you'd like to edit to focus just on Seville and Madrid? (And personally, it might be nice to ask for going a bit more in-depth than just the names?)

Comment: While malaguena originated as a dance (the fandango), it's now rare as a dance, being way more of an instrumental (guitar).